# pandasでcsv出力をしようとするとエラーになってしまう

Tags: python, python3, pandas

pandasでcsv出力をしようとするとエラーになってしまいます。

csv_up.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd
import csv

def make_csv_for_recipt(data_for_recipt):
    df = pd.DataFrame([
      ["0001", "John", "Engineer"],
      ["0002", "ボブ", "Sales"]],
      columns=['id', 'name', 'job'])

    df.to_csv("employee.csv")
```

エラー内容は以下の通りです。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csv_up.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.3.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import pandas.core.config_init
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.3.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/config_init.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pandas.formats.format import detect_console_encoding
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.3.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/formats/format.py", line 33, in <module>
    from pandas.io.common import _get_handle, UnicodeWriter, _expand_user
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.3.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 407, in <module>
    def UnicodeReader(f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'excel'
```

pythonのバージョン

```
# python -V
Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'excel'
> ```

というのは、`csv` モジュールに `excel` という属性が無い、という意味です。
標準ライブラリの `csv` モジュールには [`csv.excel`](https://docs.python.jp/3/library/csv.html#csv.excel) が存在するはずですから、これが無いならば、読み込んでいる `csv` モジュールが標準の物ではないと考えられます。

可能性は色々ありますが、モジュール名と同名のファイル（質問の例ですと `csv.py`）をカレントディレクトリに作ってしまっていて、それがモジュールとして読み込まれてしまっているのが、こういったケースの典型です。

```
import csv
print(csv.__file__)
```

などとして確認して下さい。

Comment: 自作のモジュールをcsvと言う名前にしてしまったとか、ありがちな問題ではないかと思います。